# error holder.setText() Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Estoy intentando crear un adaptador para mostrar mi RecyclerView. En la clase onBindViewHolder (sirve para comunicación entre nuestro adatpador y la calse viewHolderEntradas creada) al intentar pasar a mi textView un entero, me da un error en tiempo de ejecución y el programa se para.

`public void onBindViewHolder(viewHolderEntradas holder, int i) {`

```
   holder.variedad.setText(listEntradas.get(i).getVariedad());
   //la siguiente linea es la que da error.
  // holder.kilos.setText(Integer.toString(listEntradas.get(i).getKilos()));
   holder.fecha.setText(listEntradas.get(i).getFecha());
}
```

He probado con `holder.kilos.setText((int)(listEntradas.get(i).getKilos()));` y sigue sin funcionar también.

Comment: Intenta colocarlo de esta forma: `holder.kilos.setText(String.valueOf(listEntradas.get(i).getKilos()));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguramente estas obteniendo el error:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xxxxx

Si son valores enteros y usas el método `setText()` , debes convertir el valor a String ya que de otra forma estarías tratando de definir un id de un recurso en el sistema.

Para convertir el valor int a String,  puedes usar el método `String.valueOf()` :

```
holder.kilos.setText(String.valueOf(listEntradas.get(i).getKilos()));
```

o también:

```
holder.kilos.setText("" + listEntradas.get(i).getKilos());
```

Comment: funciona perfecto ya, muchas gracias.